# Understanding c loops due to getchar

Tags: c, arrays, function, char, stdio

I'm asking help for the following program, with which I've struggled several hours this afternoon.

I'd like to create a function that receives an array of character (Which belongs to the alphabet `A = {a,b,c}`) and its dim and return 1 in case the character belongs to language L, or 0 if not.

The language was : `a^k b^n c^m`, such that `k,m>=0` and `n>0`.

I tried very hard and i'm going to post what I've accomplished but my method seems extremely long (besides its lack of functioning)

And I'd like to know how could I think in terms of improving my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int array(char v[], int dim) {
   int i, j, k, trovato = 1;
   if (v[0] == 'c') trovato = 0;

   if (v[0] == 'a') {
      for (i = 1; i < dim; i++) {
         while (trovato == 1) {
            if (v[i] == 'c')
               trovato = 0;
            else if (v[i] == 'b') {
               trovato = 1;
               for (j = i + 1; j < dim; j++) {
                  while (trovato == 1) {
                     if (v[j] == 'a') trovato = 0;
                     if (v[j] == 'b')
                        trovato = 1;
                     else if (v[j] == 'c') {
                        trovato = 1;
                        for (k = j + 1; k < dim; k++) {
                           while (trovato == 1) {
                              if (v[k] == 'c')
                                 trovato = 1;
                              else
                                 trovato = 0;
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   if (v[0] == 'b') {
      for (i = 1; i < dim; i++) {
         while (trovato == 1) {
            if (v[i] == 'a') trovato = 0;
            if (v[i] == 'b')
               trovato = 1;
            else if (v[i] == 'c') {
               trovato = 1;
               for (j = i; j < dim; j++) {
                  while (trovato == 1) {
                     if (v[j] != 'c')
                        trovato = 0;
                     else
                        trovato = 1;
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   return trovato;
}

int main() {
   char d;
   int DIM, i = 0, k;
   scanf("%d", &DIM);
   char r[DIM];
   scanf("%c", &d);
   d = getchar();
   while (d != '\n') {
      r[i] = d;
      i++;
      scanf("%c", &d);
      d = getchar();
   }
   k = array(r, DIM);
   printf("%d\n", k);
   return 0;
}
```

What i'm really not getting is why the input is going on, like if it was in a while-loop.

I think the problem is my understanding of `getchar` and `scanf` on character, so these lines for examples:

```
scanf("%c",&d);
d=getchar();
```

And how an array of vector should be initialized?

What I'm really concerned about is efficiency, I'm afraid not to improve so fast and right, that's why I'm asking even strict but constructive critics on my work that I tried to accomplish.

Comment: @P.P. Thank you! Any link to do that ?

Comment: isn't this *way too complicated*? You just need to count consecutive `a`s, then `b`s and then `c`s; and bail out if you get anything unexpected, like `d` or `a` not followed by `b`; then check the values

Comment: @AnttiHaapala in input i can put only a b and c, the problem with counting is that i have to do cases on the following element of the array starting even with first element, because the order counts, isn't this true ? If you have a quick solution i'll be happy to hear it!

Comment: As an aside, there is a tool that can turn regular expressions into C code, http://re2c.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to make it simpler. We calculate a pointer that is one past the end of the array (v + dim) so that we don't need to use indexing and index variables, but can modify the `v` pointer itself.

```
int matches(const char *v, size_t dim) {
    const char *end = v + dim;
    size_t k = 0, m = 0, n = 0;

    // count consecutive 'a's.
    // for as long as `v` is positioned before the end
    // and points to an 'a', increment `v` and increment `k`.
    while (v < end && *v == 'a') {
        k ++;
        v ++;
    }

    // count consecutive 'b's
    while (v < end && *v == 'b') {
        m ++;
        v ++;
    }

    // count consecutive 'c's
    while (v < end && *v == 'c') {
        n ++;
        v ++;
    }

    // we didn't meet the end yet, something else was seen!
    if (v < end) {
        // not just aaa...bbbbb....cccc...
        return 0;
    }

    // there were only a's, b's, c's in that order
    else {
        check that k, m, n matches the constraints 
        and return a result based on that.
    }
}
```

So the first loop moves the pointer forward for as long as it is pointing to an `'a'`, the second for a `'b'`, and third for a `'c'` - then we ensure that we actually did come to the end, and not just a case of `abca` for example; we're incrementing `k`, `m` and `n` in the loops, so by the time the `else` clause is hit, it is true that `L = a^k b^m c^n` and you just need to check k, m, n.

No nested loops are required.

---

As for the input,

```
scanf("%c",&d);
d=getchar();
```

you're reading characters *twice*. You only need `getchar()`:

```
int c;  // getchar returns an *int*

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
    r[i ++] = d;
}
```

this is all that is required to read the input until end of file or newline.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach is to use http://re2c.org/ to generate it for you. Taken from their website,

> Its main goal is generating fast lexers: at least as fast as their reasonably optimized hand-coded counterparts.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int match(const char *const s) {
    const char *t = s, *marker;
    /*!re2c
        re2c:yyfill:enable = 0;
        re2c:define:YYCTYPE = char;
        re2c:define:YYCURSOR = t;
        re2c:define:YYMARKER = marker;

        pattern = 'a'* 'b'+ 'c'*;
        end = '\n'? "\x00";
        *           { return 0; }
        pattern end { return 1; }
    */
}

int main(void) {
    char a[512];
    while(fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin))
        printf("[%s] %s", match(a) ? "passed" : "reject", a);
    if(errno) return perror("input"), EXIT_FAILURE;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Generating `re2c a.re > a.c`,

```
/* Generated by re2c 1.0.3 on Sun Oct 21 18:38:31 2018 */
#line 1 "a.re"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#line 6 "a.re"


static int match(const char *const s) {
    const char *t = s, *marker;

#line 14 "<stdout>"
{
    char yych;
    yych = *t;
    switch (yych) {
    case 'A':
    case 'a':   goto yy4;
    case 'B':
    case 'b':   goto yy5;
    default:    goto yy2;
    }
yy2:
    ++t;
yy3:
#line 18 "a.re"
    { return 0; }
#line 30 "<stdout>"
yy4:
    yych = *(marker = ++t);
    switch (yych) {
    case 'A':
    case 'B':
    case 'a':
    case 'b':   goto yy7;
    default:    goto yy3;
    }
yy5:
    yych = *(marker = ++t);
    switch (yych) {
    case 0x00:
    case '\n':
    case 'B':
    case 'C':
    case 'b':
    case 'c':   goto yy10;
    default:    goto yy3;
    }
yy6:
    yych = *++t;
yy7:
    switch (yych) {
    case 'A':
    case 'a':   goto yy6;
    case 'B':
    case 'b':   goto yy9;
    default:    goto yy8;
    }
yy8:
    t = marker;
    goto yy3;
yy9:
    yych = *++t;
yy10:
    switch (yych) {
    case 0x00:  goto yy11;
    case '\n':  goto yy13;
    case 'B':
    case 'b':   goto yy9;
    case 'C':
    case 'c':   goto yy14;
    default:    goto yy8;
    }
yy11:
    ++t;
#line 19 "a.re"
    { return 1; }
#line 80 "<stdout>"
yy13:
    yych = *++t;
    if (yych <= 0x00) goto yy11;
    goto yy8;
yy14:
    yych = *++t;
    switch (yych) {
    case 0x00:  goto yy11;
    case '\n':  goto yy13;
    case 'C':
    case 'c':   goto yy14;
    default:    goto yy8;
    }
}
#line 20 "a.re"

}

int main(void) {
    char a[512];
    while(fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin))
        printf("[%s] %s", match(a) ? "passed" : "reject", a);
    if(errno) return perror("input"), EXIT_FAILURE;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

One can get case-sensitive output and a lot of other options, see http://re2c.org/manual/options/options.html.

Comment: Kind of too complex for me, thank you anyway but i'll really try to understand it anyway

Comment: @jacopoburelli that's automatically generated state machine, not really human-readable as such ;)